# How i can sort 2 dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

how can sort the following array

```
Array
(
    [17] => Array
        (
            [network_id] => 17
            [network_name] => M4N
            [total_transactions] => 4
            [commission] => 6.08
            [ordervalue] => 101
            [pending] => 0
            [approved] => 4
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [network_id] => 18
            [network_name] => Zanox
            [total_transactions] => 32
            [commission] => 33.7
            [ordervalue] => 1010.45
            [pending] => 0
            [approved] => 32
        )
)
```

I want to sort the above array by following sort options

- No of Transactions (high to low)
- Commission (high to low)
- Order value (high to low)

I am trying to sort it by using `array_multisort` but not success so far

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424003/sort-php-different-format-multidimensional-array-on-key) answer of mine. This might help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15062210/how-do-i-sort-the-follwing-array/15062573#15062573

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476085/how-to-sort-array-in-descending-order-based-on-a-specific-value/15476161#15476161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function sort_custom_array($arr,$key,$sort='asc'){
 foreach($arr as &$r){
       $network_id[] = $r['network_id'];
       $network_name[] = $r['network_name'];
       $total_transactions[] = $r['total_transactions'];
       $commission[] = $r['commission'];
       $ordervalue[] = $r['ordervalue'];
       $pending[] = $r['pending'];
       $approved[] = $r['approved'];
 }
 $sort = ($sort=='asc')? constant('SORT_ASC') : constant('SORT_DESC');
 switch($key){
  case 'network_id': 
     array_multisort($network_id, $sort, $arr);
  break;
  case 'network_name': 
     array_multisort($network_name, SORT_NATURAL , $arr);
     if($sort==3){
       $arr = array_reverse($arr, true);
     }
  break;
  case 'total_transactions': 
     array_multisort($total_transactions, $sort, $arr);
  break;
  case 'commission': 
     array_multisort($commission, $sort, $arr);
  break;
  case 'ordervalue': 
     array_multisort($ordervalue, $sort, $arr);
  break;
  case 'pending': 
     array_multisort($pending, $sort, $arr);
  break;
  case 'approved': 
     array_multisort($approved, $sort, $arr);
  break;
 }
  return $arr;
}
```

Now you can sort fields in this array like below:

```
$arr1 = sort_custom_array($arr,'ordervalue','desc');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr1);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/98454)

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort(); to sort by a user-defined comparison.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php